# countdown timer using javascript should not restart on reload

Tags: javascript, html

I have a timer in my checkout page, we have a 2 step checkout after step1 the web page reloads to step2 and hence the timer restarts. I need the timer to continue

Here is my code

This is javascript

```
 <input type="hidden" id="dealCost" name="dealCost" value="${model.dealCost}"/>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var dealCst = document.getElementById('dealCost').value;

  if(dealCst < 53){
  zi_inceput1 = new Date();
  ceas_start1 = zi_inceput1.getTime();

  function initStopwatch1() {
      var timp_pe_pag1 = new Date();
      return ((timp_pe_pag1.getTime() + (1000 * 0) - ceas_start1) / 1000);
  }
  var tim = 1200;
  function getSecs1() {
      var tSecs1 = Math.round(initStopwatch1());
      if((tim-tSecs1)>=0)
      {
      var iSecs1 = (tim-tSecs1) % 60;

      var iMins1 = Math.round((tSecs1 - 30) / 60);
      var iHour1 = Math.round((iMins1 - 30) / 60);
      var iMins1 = iMins1 % 60;
      var min = Math.floor((tim-tSecs1) / 60);
      if(min<10){
         min = "0"+min;
      }
      var iHour1 = iHour1 % 24;
      var sSecs1 = "" + ((iSecs1 > 9) ? iSecs1 : "0" + iSecs1);
      var sMins1 = "" + ((iMins1 > 9) ? iMins1 : "0" + iMins1);
      var sHour1 = "" + ((iHour1 > 9) ? iHour1 : "0" + iHour1);
      document.getElementById('checkout_timer').innerHTML = min + ":" + sSecs1;
      window.setTimeout('getSecs1()', 1000);
  }
  else{
      window.location.href="/deals";
  }
  }
  window.setTimeout('getSecs1()', 1000);
  }
 </script>
```

This is the html code

```
 <c:if test='${model.dealCost < 53}'>
 <div class="timer" style="float: right; width: 210px; font-size: 15px; margin-right: 20px;">
<div style="margin-top:20px;padding-bottom:5px;box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);background: white;overflow:none;">
    <div class="otherheadercheckout"><div class="otherheadertextcheckout"><img src="/images/little_white_shopping_cart-19x19.png">&nbsp;Timer</div></div>
    <p align="center">Time left to checkout</p>
    <div align="center" style="font-weight:600;">
        <span id="checkout_timer"></span>
    </div>

</div>

 </div>
 </c:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the state of the timer from one page load to the next, then you have to specifically store the timer information somewhere that persists from one page to the next.  Javascript variables are not saved from one page load to the next - they are reinitialized from scratch each time the page loads.

Your options are:

1. Server-side: use ajax to save the timer state to your server so it can be put into subsequent page loads.  This is troublesome because unless you know right when the user is leaving the page and can save the remaining time to the server reliably at that moment, any sort of timer save precision would require a lot of ajax calls to the server to constantly save the time.
2. Client-side: Store the timer state locally via a cookie or (in newer browsers) local storage.  This is easy, but can be easily manipulated by a hacker (if you care).

Comment: @prakash - we don't write your code for you.  If you want code for reading and writing cookies, you can see that code here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html (which a Google search could find for future reference).  Write the timer state to the cookie every 10 seconds or so, clear the cookie when the timer finishes.  Then, when you load the page, check to see if a timer value exists in the cookie - if so, start your timer from that value.

Comment: I would personally go for a localStorage shiv that falls back to using cookies. Two birds with one stone.

Comment: @JulianH.Lam - just curious, why involve a shim here?  This is completely solved for all browsers with a cookie value.

Comment: @jfriend00 A personal preference, for me. Cookies are completely supported, definitely. It's just a lot more fun to play with localStorage :)

Comment: thanks while creating the cookie we have a parameter "days". I need it to be few seconds. what should I do?

Comment: sorry I am very much new to cookies please help me out

Comment: @prakash - The "days" value is how long the cookie lasts in the browser before the browser removes it.  You can set that to one day or however many days you want the time to persist.  The timer value goes in the "value" part of the cookie, not in the days slot.

Comment: my problem is when the user goes back and then again comes to the timer page the timer needs restart from beginning. I need to erase the cookie.

Comment: @prakash - so what's the issue?  When your code detects you need to erase or reset the cookie, do so.

Comment: when I go back and return to the timer page the timer should begin from initial(for me it 20 minutes).